# Retrofit 2 Authenticator and Interceptor doesn't get called

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit2, okhttp

i'm trying to send an authorization to the server in the headers of any request i tried at first using the Interceptor and then when i was searching and i found the authenticator and i gave it a try but it doesn't get called and i still get 401 in the responses.

this is my code :

```
public static ElasticApiRetrofitServiceClient getElasticApiRetrofitServiceClient() {

        if (elasticApiRetrofitServiceClient == null) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            client.newBuilder()
                    .connectTimeout(Const.TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(Const.TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .authenticator(new MyInterceptor())
                    .addInterceptor(new MyInterceptor()).build();


            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(ELASTIC_BASE_URL)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            elasticApiRetrofitServiceClient = retrofit.create(ElasticApiRetrofitServiceClient.class);
        }
        return elasticApiRetrofitServiceClient;
    }
```

and this is my Interceptor/Authenticator

```
class MyInterceptor : Interceptor, Authenticator {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val originalRequest = chain.request();

        val newRequest = originalRequest . newBuilder ()
            .header("Authorization", "SOME_TOKEN")
            .build();

        return chain.proceed(newRequest);
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun authenticate (route: Route?, response: Response?): Request? {
        var requestAvailable: Request? = null
        try {
            requestAvailable = response?.request()?.newBuilder()
                ?.addHeader("Authorization", "SOME_TOKEN")
                ?.build()
            return requestAvailable
        } catch (ex: Exception) { }
        return requestAvailable
    }
}
```

the problem is i debugged multiple times and it the interceptor/authenticator never get called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `newBuilder` method on `OkHttpClient` which will create a new builder and you're not using that builder but you instead are using the old builder.

```java
public static ElasticApiRetrofitServiceClient getElasticApiRetrofitServiceClient() {

        if (elasticApiRetrofitServiceClient == null) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .connectTimeout(Const.TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(Const.TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .authenticator(new MyInterceptor())
                    .addInterceptor(new MyInterceptor()).build();


            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(ELASTIC_BASE_URL)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            elasticApiRetrofitServiceClient = retrofit.create(ElasticApiRetrofitServiceClient.class);
        }
        return elasticApiRetrofitServiceClient;
    }
```